# asp.net detect/react to changes in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I'm working on a project which I'll give a quick overview of and then my problem.

The communication chain is like this:

```
Zigbee sensors <-> Raspberry pi with zigbee radio  <-> API <-> (sever,db)
```

The database contains data about each sensor (id, which raspberry pi they belong to, if the raspberry pi can find them)
So a sensor object will look like this:

```
{"id": "2",
"panId": "1234",
"communicationDeviceId": "null",
"recognized": "false"}
```

The purpose of the system is that the raspberry pi will tell the server which sensors it found. So if the raspberry pi is supposed to find 3 sensors, ex. 1, 2 and 3 and it only finds the first to, it will send an API call witch updates the two sensors recognized field with "true".

So far I have it set up so the Raspberry pi can find out which sensors it needs to search for by making this call: "api/v1/communicationdevice/id/sensors" where id is the id of the raspberry pi. Note: communicationdevice is the raspberry pi

For updating the sensors I have made a PUT method like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] ICollection<Sensor> changedSensors )
        {
            if (_repo.ChangeSensors(changedSensors) && _repo.Save())
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, changedSensors);
        }
```

where _repo.changeSensors(changedSensors) looks like this:

```
        public bool ChangeSensors(ICollection<Sensor> sensors)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var sensor in sensors)
            {
                _ctx.Entry(sensor).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I've tested this functionality and it works as intended.

I'm deploying on Microsoft Azure and using an SQL Server db.

My question is:
How do I make my system react to the update and test if all sensors associated with that raspberry pi have had their "recognized" field set to true?

Comment: react means refresh ASP.net page on changing on DB ? In this case see [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: I want somekind of indicator that the raspberry pi was unable to find all sensors and have that in an entry in the database which a client can collect and show an error message. If that is clearer.

Comment: You can use [SingnalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: Okay I will look into SignalR. I have a membership at pluralsight, they probably have some useful resources. Thanks Max.